# How to add fabric js texture on top of svg texture threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, fabricjs

I'm creating 3d customizer with threejs and i wanted to add fabric js texture on top of it, here's what i got so far

[image]

notice that editor canvas is so big, it because i need to set the width and height according to svg texture size which is 2048, if i change the texture to 256

[image]

lists of colors and texts are not showing, with no error on the console thats why right now i set it to 2048.

If i move texts or shape from fabricjs canvas, all of the materials will be displace by fabricjs canvas like this

[image]

here's how i map the texture

```
function set_materials(response) {

    var baseSvg = document.getElementById("svgContainer").querySelector("svg");
    var baseSvgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(baseSvg);

    $('#svgPathContainer').empty();
    $('#svgTextContainer').empty();
    $('#svgPathContainer').append(baseSvgData).html();
    $('#svgTextContainer').append(baseSvgData).html();
    var texts = $('#svgPathContainer text');
    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        $(texts[i]).remove();
    }
    var paths = $('#svgTextContainer path');
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        $(paths[i]).remove();
    }
    var svg = document.getElementById("svgPathContainer").querySelector("svg");
    var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg);
    canvas.width = $(svg).width();
    canvas.height = $(svg).height();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var material;
    img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgData))));

    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var oImg = document.createElement("img");
        oImg.width = "100px";
        oImg.height = "100px";
        oImg.setAttribute("src", 'assets/' + gender + '/cat' + category + '/texture.png');
        oImg.onload = function () {
            ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4;
            ctx.scale(0.3, 0.3);
            var pattern = ctx.createPattern(oImg, 'repeat');
            ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width * 3.33, canvas.height * 3.33);
            ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
            ctx.scale(3.33, 3.33);
            var svgText = document.getElementById("svgTextContainer").querySelector("svg");
            var svgTextData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svgText);
            var imgT = document.createElement("img");
            imgT.setAttribute("src", "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svgTextData))));
            imgT.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(imgT, 0, 0);
                //TEXTURE IS FABRICJS CANVAS 
                texture.needsUpdate = true;
                texture.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();
                map = texture;
                textureMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: map });
                load_materials();
                load_styles();
                response(true);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

`texture.needsUpdate = true;` is called inside `animate` function. i think i'm doing it wrong, can someone pls explain why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: I am not really sure what your question is, to be honest. I am not sure what issues you are showing us? The loading/not loading of fonts etc... Is not something fabric takes care of, so changing the size of fabric wouldn't be the cause for your rendering issue. Fabric.js isn't even part of the above code. (Unrelated tip for the future: going fabric -> svg -> dataURL -> img -> textureCanvas -> WebGLTexture is a very heavy chain to get consistent framerates with. You should aim for fabric -> (use fabric.renderObjects) > textureCanvas to directly draw to your texture).

Comment: Actually, that might be your problem. Converting a SVG to data URL works, but the fonts loaded on your page are not available to the document displayed in the `Image`. This could be the source of your missing fonts. Better to directly render the contents of the fabric to a prepared context.

Comment: yeah i think i should remove the svg textures, and just use fabricjs only for texture, but do u know how to separate the materials? such as collar, base, pocket and etc?

Comment: the problem i'm facing is, i loaded the svg texture and it works, then i added the fabricjs canvas as texture also this is works, but after combining two of them, first load svg texture appear, then if i click fabricjs canvas, svg texture on the model disappear